# imageOutput Shiny, limited to one image (the last one)

Tags: r, shiny, rstudio

I am placing several images into a Shiny app using the `imageOutput` function as follows, but only the last image is shown. Is this because `imageOutput` is limited to only one image?

```
# ui.R
library(shiny)
library(png)
library(DT)

shinyUI(navbarPage(
  title = " Nanoproject",

  # first panel , create table of the peaksTable dataframe 
  tabPanel('Peak Table' , 
           dataTableOutput("table1")),

  # second panel
  tabPanel('Peak Images' , 
           imageOutput("image1",width=100,height=100),
           imageOutput("image2",width=100,height=100),
           imageOutput("image3",width=100,height=100),
           imageOutput("image4",width=100,height=100),
           imageOutput("image5",width=100,height=100),
           imageOutput("image6",width=100,height=100),
           imageOutput("image7",width=100,height=100),
           imageOutput("image8",width=100,height=100),
           imageOutput("image9",width=100,height=100),
           imageOutput("image10",width=100,height=100),
           imageOutput("image11",width=100,height=100)
  ),

  # third panel

  tabPanel('Event Table' , dataTableOutput("table3")),

  # fourth panel
  tabPanel('Event Images')
))

#server.R
# the peak images, 1-12   
output$image1 <- renderImage({list(src=paste0(imagePath,"/peak1.png"))},deleteFile=FALSE)
output$image2 <- renderImage({list(src=paste0(imagePath,"/peak2.png"))},deleteFile=FALSE)
output$image3 <- renderImage({list(src=paste0(imagePath,"/peak3.png"))},deleteFile=FALSE)
output$image4 <- renderImage({list(src=paste0(imagePath,"/peak4.png"))},deleteFile=FALSE)
output$image5 <- renderImage({list(src=paste0(imagePath,"/peak5.png"))},deleteFile=FALSE)
output$image6 <- renderImage({list(src=paste0(imagePath,"/peak6.png"))},deleteFile=FALSE)
output$image7 <- renderImage({list(src=paste0(imagePath,"/peak7.png"))},deleteFile=FALSE)
output$image8 <- renderImage({list(src=paste0(imagePath,"/peak8.png"))},deleteFile=FALSE)
output$image9 <- renderImage({list(src=paste0(imagePath,"/peak9.png"))},deleteFile=FALSE)
output$image10 <- renderImage({list(src=paste0(imagePath,"/peak10.png"))},deleteFile=FALSE)
output$image11 <- renderImage({list(src=paste0(imagePath,"/peak11.png"))},deleteFile=FALSE)
```

but, only the **LAST** image is loaded

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What is the actual size of the image file(s)?

I tried the following code (filename1, filename2, filename3 are just some local path names of image files), and it works fine in the case where the image sizes are smaller AND DOES NOT WORK (renders overlapping way) when the image sizes are very large. It looks like only the last image is rendered, but reality is all others are hidden underneath.

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage('Peak Images',
               imageOutput("image1"),
               imageOutput("image2"),
               imageOutput("image3"))

server <- function(input, output) {
  output$image1 <- renderImage({
    list(src = filename1)
  }, deleteFile = FALSE)
  output$image2 <- renderImage({
    list(src = filename2)
  }, deleteFile = FALSE)
  output$image3 <- renderImage({
    list(src = filename3)
  }, deleteFile = FALSE)
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: They're a ~100KB but, they are tall and wide images.

Comment: Pixel width and heigh of the images matters. When I had 240 x 340 size, all three images rendered vertically. When the image size was 25xx times 19xx something, they all rendered one on top of another.

Comment: Try my code supplying it same image file, and also by resizing that image file to smaller size.

Comment: It does look like the second image is overlapping the majority of the first image. How can I change that

Answer (score 0):

The height and width were set to "auto," which fixed the problem. Kudos to user3949008 for helping me realize that the height and width needed to be changed.